# API to download content as file

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I would like to create an API which returns a text file.
In Symfony I have a controller which is :

```
            throw $this->createNotFoundException($message);
        }
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', "text/cfg;charset=utf-8");
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.cfg"');
        $response->headers->set('Pragma', "no-cache");
        $response->headers->set('Expires', "0");
        $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', "binary");
        $response->headers->set('Content-Length', strlen($data));
        $response->setContent($data);
        return $response;
```

Is there any alternative option with api-platform to explain this format ?
I'm in symfony 4 with api-plateform

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use symfony's alias I guess (not an api platform user so idk what is installed exactly).

```php
return $this->file($txtPath, 'sample.txt', ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the file is not an existing file.
I generate the content with my var $data.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a subclass of `Response`. This class for example return images of some $format.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Services\Response;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ImageResponse extends Response
{
    public function __construct(string $content, string $filename, string $format)
    {
        parent::__construct($content, 200, [
            'Cache-Control' => 'private',
            'Content-type' => "image/$format",
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";',
            'Content-length' => strlen($content)
        ]);
    }
}
```

I really don't know if is correct or a good practice, it just works: when you return a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` from an state provider Api Platform use it as the final response. Don't use a Controller, you can use an state provider. Currently I never use controllers and probably I will never use them again.

Use `openapiContext` to correctly describe the response. Read the [specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/) to know how to describe responses:

For example:

```php
#[Api\Get(
    uriTemplate: "book/{id}",
    formats: ['ms-word' => ['application/vnd.openxmlformats']],
    openapiContext: [
        'summary' => self::GET_SUMMARY,
        'description' => self::GET_SUMMARY,
        'parameters' => [
            ['in' => 'path', 'name' => 'id', 'description' => 'The document id', 'required' => true, 'schema' => ['type' => 'integer']]
        ],
        'responses' => [
            200 => [
                'description' => 'The book in MS Word format',
                'content' => [
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats' => [
                        'schema' => [
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'format' => 'binary'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    security: "is_granted('ROLE_READ_BOOK')",
    provider: BookProvider::class,
)]
```